# checked in input not working for html+php

Tags: html, input, checkbox, checked

I'm having some trouble with the `<input>` HTML tag. I try to make one box checked but it isn't working. The HTML file is running with PHP. As you can see I used the default checked in the input. But it isn't working. How can I fix this without jQuery?

```
<fieldset id="imageselector">
 <label id="labelog" class="container imageinput" style="display:none;">
   <input id="Radioog" name="radio" class="radio" type="radio" value="img" checked/>
   <img id="selector_image" class="selector_image"  src="//youtube.com/yts/img/yt_1200-vflhSIVnY.png">
   <span class="imagecheckmark"></span>
 </label>
 <label id="labelimg" class="container imageinput" style="display:none;">
   <input id="Radioimg" name="radio" class="radio" type="radio" value="og"/>
   <img id="selector_og" class="selector_image" src="//youtube.com/yts/img/yt_1200-vflhSIVnY.png">
   <span class="imagecheckmark"></span>
 </label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `display: none` on your label, this element is wrapping your radio inputs so none of that will show up. If you remove that, checked is working fine.

Comment: already tried that, not working. Also with some jQuery later the display:none is removed, so then I assume it should be visible right?

Comment: Edit your question and add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that will help to fix your issue.

Comment: If you're removing all attrs when you switch display:none off then you're removing the checked attr as well, but if you're directly modifying the style attr then it might be something else going on. Without seeing the code it's hard to speculate.

Comment: but I'm no where able to reproduce it. It only happens over there.And no it cann't be the display:none, because without them it isn't working either.

Comment: Then there is no way anyone can help you. What you shared is HTML only and the HTML works, something in your project is causing it not to work, hence why you can't reproduce the issue. If your problem with sharing is that you don't know how there are plenty of PHP enabled online code editors like [tehplayground] which support PHP, however, if you just don't want to share then you will need to debug your own issues.